# Realm React-native error

Tags: react-native, realm

I'm having this error when I try to install Realm with my react-native android app:

```
npm install --save realm

> -realm@0.15.0 install C:\Users\Julia\AppTest\node_modules\realm

> -node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

>node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(404): https://static.realm.io/node-pre-gyp/realm-v0.15.0-node-v48-win32-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for realm@0.15.0 and node@6.9.1 (node-v48 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)

C:\Users\Julia\AppTest\node_modules\realm>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" clean )  else (node "" clean )

C:\Users\Julia\AppTest\node_modules\realm>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\Julia\AppTest\node_modules\realm\compiled\node-v48_win32_x64\realm.node --module_name=realm --module_path=C:\Users\Julia\AppTest\node_modules\realm\compiled\node-v48_win32_x64 )  else (node "" configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\Julia\AppTest\node_modules\realm\compiled\node-v48_win32_x64\realm.node --module_name=realm --module_path=C:\Users\Julia\AppTest\node_modules\realm\compiled\node-v48_win32_x64 )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:449:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:404:11
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Users\\Julia\\AppTest\\node_modules\\realm\\compiled\\node-v48_win32_x64\\realm.node" "--module_name=realm" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\Julia\\AppTest\\node_modules\\realm\\compiled\\node-v48_win32_x64"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Julia\AppTest\node_modules\realm
gyp ERR! node -v v6.9.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'node-gyp.cmd configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\Julia\AppTest\node_modules\realm\compiled\node-v48_win32_x64\realm.node --module_name=realm --module_path=C:\Users\Julia\AppTest\node_modules\realm\compiled\node-v48_win32_x64' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Julia\AppTest\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Julia\\AppTest\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Julia\AppTest\node_modules\realm
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v6.9.1
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.32
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'node-gyp.cmd configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\Julia\AppTest\node_modules\realm\compiled\node-v48_win32_x64\realm.node --module_name=realm --module_path=C:\Users\Julia\AppTest\node_modules\realm\compiled\node-v48_win32_x64' (1)
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save" "realm"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! realm@0.15.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the realm@0.15.0 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the realm package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs realm
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls realm
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Julia\AppTest\npm-debug.log
```

What do I do? I'm following the steps on the page 'https://realm.io/docs/react-native/latest/#getting-started', however when I install Realm on the command Promt I get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We currently have an issue with React Native when developing on a Windows machine. We are working on fixing it, you can keep track of the issue [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/674)